# On the existence of non-trivial solution for a linear second order boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across with a multiple choice question:

The ODE$$-y^{\prime \prime}+(1+x) y=\lambda y, x \in(0,1), y(0)=y(1)=0$$ has a non-zero solution

(1) $\forall \lambda \in[0,1]$

(2) $\forall \lambda<0$

(3) for some $\lambda \in[2, \infty)$

(4) for a countable number of $\lambda^{\prime} s$

Option 1 and 2 can be rejected since for any $\lambda<1$, we have $Q(x)=\lambda-(1+x)<0$, which is not possible since $y$ has already two zeros in [0,1]. I have seen several answers on the same question in this platform, but none of them convincing me for the existence of non-trivial solutions for $\lambda \geq 2$.

Can we have some special regularity conditions for a second order linear boundary value problem:
$$y''+Q(x)y=0,y(a)=y_1,y(b)=y_2$$
to have a non-trivial solution?

The same difficulty of existence of non-trivial solutions I have faced with the 2 and 4 th option in another multiple choice question:

Consider the eigenvalue problem $$\left(\left(1+x^{4}\right) y^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+\lambda y=0, x \in(0,1), y(0)=0, y(1)+2 y^{\prime}(1)=0.$$ Then which of the following statements are true?

1. all the eigenvalues are negative
2. all the eigenvalues are positive
3. there exists some negative eigenvalues and some positive eigenvalues
4. there are no eigenvalues

Since regular SLP problem cannot have negative eigen values, we can reject 1 and 3. Also for $\lambda=0,$ I got $y=0$ is only solution by some alterations in the boundary conditions to get an IVP:

$$(1+x^4)y''+4x^3y'=0, y(0)=0,y'(0)=-y(1),$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non-trivial solution of the BVP will have $y'(0)\ne 0$ (else the IVP gives the zero solution). Thus the solution can be scaled to $y'(0)=1$.

Denote $y(x;λ)$ the solutions of the IVP $y''+( λ-1-x)y=0$, $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$. Finding a solution to the BVP is equivalent to finding a root of $y(1;λ)$. This is a continuous function in $λ$. Also the roots $z_n(λ)$ of $y(x;λ)$ depend continuously on $λ$. As there can be no double roots (would imply zero solution), there will also be no fold points or other singularities in the paths of the roots.

Set $\omega_n=\pi n$. Then with the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem, and a suitably small $ε,δ>0$,

- if $λ-1<ω_n^2$ then $y$ will have at most $n-1$ positive roots in $(0,1]$, $z_n(λ)>1$,

  - as between any two roots of $y$ there has to be one of the $n-1$ roots of $\sin((n\pi-ε) (x+\delta))$. $δ>0$ is chosen with $(n\pi-ε) (1+\delta)<n\pi$, so that there are roots just outside the interval on both sides.
- if $λ-2>ω_n^2$ then $y$ will have at least $n$ positive roots in $(0,1]$, $z_n(λ)\le 1$,

  - as between any two of the $(n+1)$ roots of $\sin((n\pi+ε)(x-δ))$ in $(0,1]$ there has to be a root of $y$. Here $δ>0$ is chosen so that $(n\pi+ε)(1-δ)>n\pi$, so that the two roots close to the interval boundaries are just inside the interval.

In the transition from one case to the next the $n$th root $z_n(λ)$ has to transition into the interval, thus $z_n(λ)=1$ at some $λ\in(ω_n^2+1,ω_n^2+2)$. Which in turn means the solution $y$ will have a root at the interval boundary $1$, giving a solution to the eigenvalue problem. As there is one distinct solution for each $n$, case (4) is true, and obviously also case (3).

**Illustration for the case $n=2$**

[image: plots of solutions and sinusoids]

The dotted curves are the solutions for blue: $λ=(2\pi)^2$ and red: $λ=(2\pi)^2+3$. The thin lines are suitably shifted sine functions $\sin((2\pi\pm0.1)(x\mp0.01))$ clearly separating the cases of 1 and 2 positive roots.

Comment: Sir, How can we convert the BVP in the post in to an IVP as in your answer?

Comment: The equation is homogeneous in $y$. Thus any non-trivial solution, having $y'(0)\ne 0$, can be scaled to have $y'(0)=1$. Turning that around, for any $λ$ the value $y(1;λ)$ (making the parameter of the equation explicit) is a continuous (smooth) function of $λ$ if the initial conditions are fixed that way, eigenvalues of the original problem are exactly the roots of this function.

Comment: Sir,  How can we confirm $y'(0)\neq 0$?

Comment: Because with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ you get the zero solution, and the assumption was that there is a non-zero solution.

Comment: Actually we are checking the truth value of 'The BVP (described in the post) has a non zero solution for some $\lambda \geq 2$', right?

Comment: Sir, I got that: 'The BVP (described in the post) has a non zero solution' if and only if '$y'(0)\neq 0$' and this is sufficient for $\lambda \geq 2$. But how to confirm $\lambda \geq 2$ implies BVP has non -trivial solution.

Comment: That is explained in the answer, over the interval $λ\in[ω^2_n+1,ω^2_n+2]$, the continuous function $y(1;λ)$ will have a sign change.

Comment: Sir, Can you suggest some reference especially for '' finding solution to the BVP is equivalent to finding the roots of $y(1;\lambda)$'' to make clear about it.

Comment: I'm not sure that there will exist sources that discuss this as separate fact, as $y(1;λ)=0$ is exactly the second boundary condition. The non-trivial fact here is that you can translate "non-zero solution" to "$y'(0;λ)=1$". Note that for eigenvalue problems any non-zero point from the eigenspace is admissible as eigenvector or eigenfunction. Other common conditions to force a non-zero solution are unit-norm conditions, such as $\int_0^2y(t;λ)\,dt=1$ for the simple $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir...

Comment: Should of course be $\int_0^1y(t;λ)^2\,dt=1$ as the norm condition.