# Justify the existence of a non trivial solution for the BVP $y''+(\lambda-(1+x))y=0, x\in (0,1),$ with $y(0)=y(1)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I want to prove there is a non-zero solution for the BVP: $$y''+(\lambda-(1+x))y=0, x\in (0,1),$$ with $y(0)=y(1)=0,$ for some $\lambda>2$.

Can we proceed the existence in the light of Theorem 7 from this [source](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.9/5102-19/D.pdf)?

I was unable to apply our SLP problem to the hypothesis of the Theorem 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408945/on-the-existence-of-non-trivial-solution-for-a-linear-second-order-boundary-valu, same equation, task as multiple-choice.

Comment: Other duplicates in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890758/y1xy-lambda-y-for-which-value-of-lambda-the-eqn-has-nonzero-soluti and linked from there.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks... and, one thing, Can we connect your answers provided above with the Theorem 7 in the this [reference](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.9/5102-19/D.pdf)? Actually I was unable to apply our SLP problem to the hypothesis of the Theorem 7.

Comment: Yes, one can use functional analysis/spectral theory or variational calculus to prove the existence of eigenvalues from general principles. The equation, as it is, is self-adjoint. One could also use the functional $Q[y]=\int_0^1(y'(x)^2+(1+x)y(x)^2)\,dx$ on the unit sphere in $H^1_0([0,1])$ and explore its minimum and stationary points

Comment: @LutzLehmann Can I expect an explained form of answer using the extremal indicated above? Actually, I am unable to capture the premises of the theorem $7$ in our problem. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Distributional theory

Theorem 7 in your source says that for a self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville operator $L[u]=\frac1w[-(pu')'+qu]$ (as provided by conditions on the coefficients) with homogeneous boundary conditions the eigenvalue equation $L[u]=\lambda u$ has solutions and

- all eigenvalues are real, the eigenspace contains/is spanned by real functions
- all eigenspaces are one-dimensional and orthogonal,
- eigenvalues form an increasing unbounded sequence $\lambda_1<\lambda_2<...<\lambda_n\to\infty$
- an orthonormal eigenbasis can be selected

---

In the concrete case, $w=1$, $p=1$ and $q(x)=1+x$, boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$ are homogeneous, so all assumptions are satisfied.

#### Using ODE and parameter dependence

Using the Sturm-Picone comparison theorem and intermediate-value arguments one can enclose the eigenvalues, see [On the existence of non-trivial solution for a linear second order boundary value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408945/on-the-existence-of-non-trivial-solution-for-a-linear-second-order-boundary-valu)

#### Sketch of the variational approach

The expression $\|u\|_A^2=\int_0^1(u'^2+(1+x)u^2)dx$ defines a norm on the Sobolev space $H^1_0([0,1])$ that is equivalent to the more standard norm $\|u\|^2=\int_0^1(u'^2+u^2)dx$.

Define $\phi(u)=\|u\|_{L^2}$, then $\phi(u)\le \|u\|_A$ is bounded and continuous.

As the Sobolev space is a Hilbert space and thus reflexive, there exists (over some steps) a maximizer $u^*$ that realizes the supremum $\mu$ of $\phi$ on the unit sphere of $\|·\|_A$. $\lambda_1=\frac1\mu$ is then the lowest eigenvalue. Then show that $u^*$ solves the ODE in the distributional sense, use order-raising arguments to find that $u^*$ also satisfies the ODE as $C^2$ function.

Alternatively and more straight-forward would be to minimize $\|u\|A^2$ on $\|u\|_{L^2}=1$. However this ball is not closed in either $H^1$ norm, so that some extra steps are required to establish a minimizer and its properties that qualify it as eigenfunction.